# $http interceptor doesn't fetch GET request with hash in its parameter

Tags: angularjs, angular-http-interceptors

I have trouble with angularjs interceptors. Here's my code:

```
    angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('httpInterceptor', ['$q', '$rootScope',
        function ($q, $rootScope) {

            return {
                request: function (config) {

                    console.log(config);
                    return config || $q.when(config);
                },
                response: function (response) {

                    console.log(config);
                    return response || $q.when(response);
                },

                responseError: function (response) {

                    return $q.reject(response);
                }
            };
        }
    ]).config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpInterceptor');
}]);
```

I have a GET request for image

.../api/download?hash=unit:logo:564&random=201701181648411382

and another GET request for json response

.../api/query/

So here's the problem. Why interseptor doesn't see the first type of request?

Second one is normally showed in console. First one was ingnored by interceptor.
Is it possible to solve this problem?

Both requests requires Auth token given by cookies. And I need to rewrite this token after every request.

Thanks

Comment: Show how you make these requests. Interceptors are not magicians - they intercept only requests done using $http or dependent (i.e. $resource) services. If request is download using <a href="../download/file"... << that request just can not be intercepted, cause it is done by browser directly.

Comment: oh, i got It. This request done by browser. There is another question then. Is there some technique to get information about this request (headers, cookies etc.) using angular?

Comment: well i know one "hack" - in angular your add some parameter to upload i.e. time in millis (t1) and store it, on server you add cookie to response with name UPLOAD_{t1}, so on UI you can create interval to check this cookie is presented or not.

Comment: Ok, I will think about that. The main problem was that I didn't understand why interceptor doesn't work on this request. Now I see why. Thanks for the answer. It was helpful